# mysqli error debugging

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been building an xml parser what should red all xml files from a folder and after parsing theme should save data in mysql table. After all I'm getting the following error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and how should i debug it.

```
Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in E:\xampp\htdocs\XML_Parser\index.php on line 38
```

my code

```
class XMLFeeds{

    public $obj;

    protected $db_connect;

    function __construct(){     
        // Read feeds and pass it to parser
        $this->db_connect = @new mysqli('loalhost', 'root', '', 'test');
        foreach(glob("feeds/*xml") as $filename) {
            $obj = $this->parsing_feed(file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT) );
            $this->saveFeed($obj);
        }   
    }

    function parsing_feed($feed){       
        return simplexml_load_string($feed);        
    }   

    function saveFeed($obj){
        foreach ($obj as $row){

                $stmt = $this->db_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl 
                        ( id,
                          prod_name,
                          category,
                          description,
                          image_url,
                          keywords,
                          sku,
                          target_url,
                          price,
                          warranty,
                          shipping_costs,
                          impressionurl,
                          lastupdated ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

                if ($stmt === FALSE) {
                    die($mysqli->error);
                }

                $stmt -> bind_param("ssi",
                         $row->name,
                         $row->advertisercategory,
                         $row->description,
                         $row->imageurl,
                         $row->keywords,
                         $row->sku,
                         $row->buyurl,
                         $row->price,
                         $row->standardshippingcostm,
                         $row->impressionurl,
                         $row->lastupdated );
                $stmt ->execute();
        }
    }
}

$parse = new XMLFeeds();
```

Comment: You shouldn't suppress errors on the database connection.

Comment: ... especially as the error might be right there (`loalhost`)

Comment: yepp to tired, typing error

Comment: sorry for this issue and thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

this happened because the connection is not established successfully with the database because the localhost is spelled wrong.
you are omitting the errors during instantiate mysqli class by using @new.

try to remove the @ and check if the connection is not establish to through an exception otherwise it will proceed with code execution .

```
    <?php
    $this->db_connect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'zanox');
    if($this->db_connect->connect_error){
       throw new Exception('unable to connect, '. $this->db_connect->connect_error);
    }
```